# please help me to double check this derivative

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Can you please help me to check whether this is correct?

$\hat{y} = \operatorname{softmax}(hU + b_2)$, 
$J = \operatorname{CrossEntropy}(y, \hat{y})$.

where $\hat{y} \in \Bbb R^{1x5}, y \in\Bbb R^{1x5}, h\in \Bbb R^{1x 30}, U \in \Bbb R^{30 x5}, b_2 \in \Bbb R^{1x5}$. And $y$ is a one hot vector (meaning only 1 entry has probability of 1, while the other entries are 0.

I want to compute the gradient with respect of L w.r.t $U$ and $b_2$.

---

**Attempt:**

$\frac{dJ}{dU} = (\operatorname{softmax}(hU+b_2) - y)h$

$\frac{dJ}{db_2} =(\operatorname{softmax}(hU+b_2) - y) $

But it looks like $dJ/dU$ should have a dimension of $30 \times 5$, this doesn't work out. Am I missing anything?

For the derivative of cross-entropy with softmax, I follow the derivation here: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2016/the-softmax-function-and-its-derivative/

Comment: can you please help me out?

Comment: One of the gradients is correct but the other should be $\frac{\partial J}{\partial U} = h^T({\hat y}-y)$

Comment: @greg, is it possible to elaborate how do you get to this step.. I actually stuck here, I do realize that I have to do that so that the final product $dJ/dU$ has a dimension of 30 x 5. But I am unable to see how come it is $h.T$

Comment: Your result is very nearly correct. Just walk us through your derivation and I'm sure someone here will be able to point out any missteps.